# Iterate through all TextViews in a ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase

Okay, I'm searching and searching for the solution.

I'm using Firebase, but don't know if its neccessary for you to know. When I edit something on the internet on Firebase, my Android app gets a callback that something got edited. So now, I have to edit it also from my app.

So, now I need to search a TextView in the Layout that a certain identifier. It's an object that holds the name and an identifier. This is how I remove it

```
Todolists itemToRemove = (Todolists)v.getTag();
Firebase listRef = new Firebase("https://av-dots.firebaseio.com/users/" + userId + "/lists/" + itemToRemove.getIdentifier());
listRef.removeValue();
adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
```

But how do I edit it? I have the identifier that is the id where I can identifiy it, but how would I edit it?

Comment: Is `listRef.removeValue();` a `Network` execution?

Comment: Are you using an actual ListView? With an adapter? In that case you should change the underlying data in the adapter and take care of its layout/text in its getView for the changed item

Comment: Yes, I'm using a ListView with an Adapter. How would I change that? I have a callback method from Firebase that is as follows 

http://pastebin.de/37907

Answer (score 1):

You can get the corresponding TextView using `findViewById`:

```java
Resources res = getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(itemToRemove.getIdentifier(), "id", getPackageName());
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(resId);
// Edit TextView as appropriate...
```